# Can I earn achievements while playing custom songs?

Tags: beat-saber

Beat Saber has [achievements](https://steamcommunity.com/stats/620980/achievements) for clearing songs under certain conditions. (Get full combo on any level on expert difficulty, clear any level with battery energy modifier, etc.)

Can these achievements be earned while playing custom songs? Or are they limited to official tracks?

Answer (score 1):

Looking around I do not see songs specifically made for the easy achievements, but I see multiple mentions of songs that I'm pretty sure are not of the official tracklist of beatsaber. https://www.reddit.com/r/beatsaber/comments/glcnus/what_is_the_best_song_i_can_install_to_get_the/

So I guess yes. You can get achievements from custom/modded songs.